# Jacobian identity used in proof of change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, determinant, jacobian, change-of-variable

This is from "Calculus on Manifolds", proof of Change of Variables theorem. I don't understand why these two red circled expressions are equal.
$$|det(h\circ g)'|=|det(h'\circ g)||det(g')|$$ by Chain Rule, but I see no way this can be further simplified to $(|det(h')|\circ g)\ \cdot |det(g')|$
[image]

Comment: Hint: Chain Rule in matrix form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it down:
$$\big(|\det h'|\circ g\big)(x) = |\det h'(g(x))| = |\det(h'\circ g)(x)|.$$
The $|\det g'|$ comes from the chain rule and multiplicativity of determinant:
$$|\det (h\circ g)'(x)| = |\det \big(h'(g(x))g'(x)\big)| = |\det h'(g(x))||\det g'(x)| = |\det(h'\circ g)(x)||\det g'(x)|,$$
as needed.

Comment: Oh, thanks, it was actually that I messed up the order of functional composition while trying to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my answer in case someone's faced with the same trouble. It is fust about the order of functional composition. In both cases we first apply $g(x)$, then $h'(x)$, then $det(x)$ and finally $|x|$